# WPF attached property set in tabcontrol being used in GridColumn header

Tags: c#, xaml

Hi My main objective is to rename gridcontrol(datagrid) column headers based on the tabitem header text. Meaning if the tabitem headertext is named "TabItem 1" I would like to take that "TabItem 1" and append some string to it and set it to a datagrid column header. The tabcontrol / tabitems header and the grid are being populated at run time by the Observable collection containing an object Headertext that will go to the tabitem header and a List which will populate the datagrid. 
I was advised to create an attached property and Valueconverter. The attached property is the first thing I am trying to achieve and after researching I got the idea that if I create an attached property I can set a value to it and be able to use it anywhere in the xaml in my case the header in a datagrid column. My issue is I set up a attached property as so:

```
 public class Ex : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        TabHeaderTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
              "TabHeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(Ex),
        new PropertyMetadata(""));
    public static string GetTabHeaderText(
        DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(TabHeaderTextProperty);
    }
    public static void SetTabHeaderText(
        DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(TabHeaderTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

and I am trying to use it in the TabControl and set the HeaderText to the attached property as so

```
<TabControl  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" Height="Auto"      Background="Transparent" x:Name="Tabs" >
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate >
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}" localHelper:Ex.TabHeaderText="{Binding  HeaderText}" />
   </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Name="Tabsitems">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="725" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1600" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text ="{Binding localHelper:Ex.TabHeaderText}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                      <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" >
                                        <dxgcore:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridColumn Name="Month1" FieldName="Month01" Visible="True" AllowEditing="False" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" CellStyle="{StaticResource NumberCellStyle}">
                                                <dxg:GridColumn.Header>


                                                    <TextBlock Text ="{Binding localHelper:Ex.TabHeaderText}" />

                                                </dxg:GridColumn.Header>
                                                <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                                    <dxe:TextEditSettings HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                                                </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                            </dxg:GridColumn>
 </dxgcore:GridControl.Columns>
                                    <dxgcore:GridControl.View>
                                        <dxgcore:TableView x:Name="View" 
                                       AllowEditing="False" 
                                       AllowBestFit="True" 
                                       AllowMoving="True" 
                                       AllowColumnFiltering="True"
                                       IsColumnMenuEnabled="True"
                                       ShowGroupPanel="False"
                                       ShowAutoFilterRow="True"
                                       AutoWidth="False" 
                                       NavigationStyle="Cell"
                                       VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Visible"
                                       HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Visible"

                                        </dxgcore:TableView>
                                    </dxgcore:GridControl.View>
                                </dxg:GridControl>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </TabControl>
```

The issue that I am getting now is that even thou I am setting the attached property (I think) to avalue HeaderText I also hardcoded (just as a test), I am not able to see it when I use it in a datagridcolumn header or just a textblock outside of the datagrid.What am I doing wrong?